# Session timeout in clickhouse cache dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, caching, clickhouse

While trying to load large clickhouse cached dictionaries I get the error:

```
2021.02.07 01:59:10.151245 [ 29676 ] {27c10a8a-f0ec-40f2-b101-265091f190ca} <Error> executeQuery: Code: 159, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Dictionary CacheDictionary source seems unavailable, because 60000ms timeout exceeded. (version 20.8.3.18) (from [::1]:54232) (in query: select dictGet('CacheDictionary', 'random0', toUInt64(1))), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. Poco::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) @ 0x13cd24bc in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) @ 0xa4346c9 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. ? @ 0x9cc8def in /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. ? @ 0xe0c7544 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. DB::CacheDictionary::getString(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, DB::PODArray<unsigned long, 4096ul, Allocator<false, false>, 15ul, 16ul> const&, DB::ColumnString*) const @ 0xe0c7d97 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. bool DB::FunctionDictGetString::executeDispatch<DB::CacheDictionary>(DB::Block&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> > const&, unsigned long, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IDictionaryBase const> const&) const @ 0xba75ff0 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. DB::FunctionDictGetString::executeImpl(DB::Block&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long) const @ 0xba9a6c0 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. DB::ExecutableFunctionAdaptor::defaultImplementationForConstantArguments(DB::Block&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool) @ 0xc09e544 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. DB::ExecutableFunctionAdaptor::executeWithoutLowCardinalityColumns(DB::Block&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool) @ 0xc09e75e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. DB::ExecutableFunctionAdaptor::execute(DB::Block&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool) @ 0xc09ef85 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. DB::ExpressionAction::prepare(DB::Block&, DB::Settings const&, std::__1::unordered_set<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >&) @ 0x1167972b in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. DB::ExpressionActions::addImpl(DB::ExpressionAction, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >&) @ 0x1167a345 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. DB::ExpressionActions::add(DB::ExpressionAction const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >&) @ 0x1167a866 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. DB::ScopeStack::addAction(DB::ExpressionAction const&) @ 0x1190b945 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
14. DB::ActionsMatcher::visit(DB::ASTFunction const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, DB::ActionsMatcher::Data&) @ 0x119166d2 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
15. DB::InDepthNodeVisitor<DB::ActionsMatcher, true, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const>::visit(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&) @ 0x11692b95 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
16. ? @ 0x11685753 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
17. DB::SelectQueryExpressionAnalyzer::appendSelect(DB::ExpressionActionsChain&, bool) @ 0x11687ad2 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
18. DB::ExpressionAnalysisResult::ExpressionAnalysisResult(DB::SelectQueryExpressionAnalyzer&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, bool, bool, bool, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::FilterInfo> const&, DB::Block const&) @ 0x1169149d in /usr/bin/clickhouse
19. DB::InterpreterSelectQuery::getSampleBlockImpl() @ 0x10d06206 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
20. ? @ 0x10d0ac88 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
21. DB::InterpreterSelectQuery::InterpreterSelectQuery(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, DB::Context const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IBlockInputStream> const&, std::__1::optional<DB::Pipe>, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IStorage> const&, DB::SelectQueryOptions const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&) @ 0x10d14197 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
22. DB::InterpreterSelectQuery::InterpreterSelectQuery(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, DB::Context const&, DB::SelectQueryOptions const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&) @ 0x10d15b76 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
23. DB::InterpreterSelectWithUnionQuery::InterpreterSelectWithUnionQuery(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, DB::Context const&, DB::SelectQueryOptions const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&) @ 0x10d33756 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
24. DB::InterpreterFactory::get(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST>&, DB::Context&, DB::QueryProcessingStage::Enum) @ 0x10cea07f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
25. ? @ 0x10e0dfa5 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
26. DB::executeQuery(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, DB::Context&, bool, DB::QueryProcessingStage::Enum, bool) @ 0x10e0fa5f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
27. DB::TCPHandler::runImpl() @ 0x1123e65c in /usr/bin/clickhouse
28. DB::TCPHandler::run() @ 0x1123f299 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
29. Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection::start() @ 0x13c11197 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
30. Poco::Net::TCPServerDispatcher::run() @ 0x13c1158b in /usr/bin/clickhouse
31. Poco::PooledThread::run() @ 0x13d481ae in /usr/bin/clickhouse
```

I've checked through this documentation: [settings](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings/) which points me towards the session timeout parameter although changing this in `config.xml` doesn't change the timeout for clickhouse.

Comment: To apply changes in *config.xml* need to restart ch-service: *sudo service clickhouse-server restart*. Which params did you change?

Comment: I changed sessionTimeout as indicated in the question: <sessionTimeout>120000</sessionTimeout> in openSSL. I have already restarted the machine that does not change anything i.e. I can't find the parameter to change.